# List of economic industries/sectors for a dropdown field (rails 3.2, active admin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a Ruby on Rails app and using Rails 3.2+active admin

one of my models is Company and i'd like to put a field where i enter for each company the sector/industry (ex: Communication, Advertising...).

but there are so many !Would you know where i could get this list(as text or as a gem) ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of sources for that, depending of what you intend to do:

- For legal issues, you can find your country economic activity codes;
- You can laso take a look at Standard Industrial Classification on wikipedia
- Or the NYSE Industry Classification Benchmark (ICB)
  http://www.nyse.com/about/listed/lc_all_industry.html
- Or the EU classification
  http://ec.europa.eu/competition/mergers/cases/index/nace_all.html

Regards

Comment: The NYSE link returns 404 - is there any other source for the whole list of Industries ?